# Remove null from pivot table (from multilple columns and different data types)

Tags: sql

i want to pivot this table to the below table (expected result)

```
CompanyID   Amount      Status  ID  Year
58          10000.00    PENDING 54  2018
59          10000.00    PENDING 55  2018
59          5300.00     PAID    56  2015
59          5300.00     PENDING 57  2013
59          10600.00    PENDING 58  2016
60          10600.00    PAID    59  2016
60          10600.00    PENDING 60  2017
60          10000.00    PENDING 61  2018
61          10000.00    PAID    62  2018
61          10600.00    PAID    63  2016
61          10600.00    PAID    64  2017
67          5300.00     PAID    65  2015
67          10600.00    PAID    66  2016
```

I'm trying using unpivot/pivot, but still doesnt work

```
CompanyID  A2015  S2015 A2016   S2016   A2017   S2017   A2018   S2018
58         NULL   NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10000.00PENDING
59         NULL   NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
59         NULL   NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10000.00PENDING
59         NULL   NULL  10600.00PENDING NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
59         5300.00PAID  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
60         NULL   NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10000.00PENDING
60         NULL   NULL  NULL    NULL    10600.00PENDING NULL    NULL
60         NULL   NULL  10600.00PAID    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
61         NULL   NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10000.00PAID
61         NULL   NULL  NULL    NULL    10600.00PAID    NULL    NULL
61         NULL   NULL  10600.00PAID    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
67         NULL   NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10000.00PAID
67         NULL   NULL  NULL    NULL    10600.00PAID    NULL    NULL
```

trying to pivot 2 different data type & multiple column in one query

```
    SELECT CompanyID,[A2015],[S2015],[A2016],[S2016],[A2017],[S2017],[A2018],[S2018]
FROM
(   SELECT CompanyID, [Status], 
    'A' + [Year] AS [Year_Amount],
    'S' + [Year] AS [Year_Status],
    (Select ORGANIZATION from [Membership].[dbo].[Members]
where ID=[Payment].CompanyID ) as Organisation,[Amount]
    FROM [Membership].[dbo].[Payment]) as sourcetable

pivot (
SUM([Amount]) for [Year_Amount] in ([A2015],[A2016],[A2017],[A2018]))
 as Pvt

pivot (
MIN([Status]) for [Year_Status] in ([S2015],[S2016],[S2017],[S2018])) 
as Pvt2
```

expected output should be like this

```
CompanyID A2015   S2015 A2016    S2016   A2017    S2017   A2018    S2018
58        NULL    NULL  NULL     NULL    NULL     NULL    10000.00 PENDING
59        5300.00 PAID  10600.00 PENDING NULL     NULL    10000.00 PENDING
60        NULL    NULL  10600.00 PAID    10600.00 PENDING 10000.00 PENDING
61        NULL    NULL  10600.00 PAID    10600.00 PAID    10000.00 PAID
67        NULL    NULL  NULL     NULL    10600.00 PAID    10000.00 PAID
```

Guys, thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here problem seems to be extra columns present in `pivot` when doing `pivoting` for Amount. I think you need to do two separate `pivoting` and then combine their results. To test this on my local box, I have created one variable table i.e., `@xyz` as shown in below script -

```
declare @xyz table (CompanyID int, Amount decimal(10,2), [Status] varchar(50), ID int, [Year] varchar(4));

insert into @xyz
          select 58, 10000.00, 'PENDING' ,54,  '2018'
union all select 59, 10000.00, 'PENDING' ,55,  '2018'
union all select 59, 5300.00 , 'PAID'    ,56,  '2015'
union all select 59, 5300.00 , 'PENDING' ,57,  '2013'
union all select 59, 10600.00, 'PENDING' ,58,  '2016'
union all select 60, 10600.00, 'PAID'    ,59,  '2016'
union all select 60, 10600.00, 'PENDING' ,60,  '2017'
union all select 60, 10000.00, 'PENDING' ,61,  '2018'
union all select 61, 10000.00, 'PAID'    ,62,  '2018'
union all select 61, 10600.00, 'PAID'    ,63,  '2016'
union all select 61, 10600.00, 'PAID'    ,64,  '2017'
union all select 67, 5300.00 , 'PAID'    ,65,  '2015'
union all select 67, 10600.00, 'PAID'    ,66,  '2016'

;WITH Amount_Pivoting AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT
            CompanyID,
            'A' + [Year] AS [Year_Amount],
            [Amount]
        FROM @xyz
        ) AS sourcetable
        PIVOT (
        SUM([Amount]) for [Year_Amount] in ([A2015],[A2016],[A2017],[A2018]))
        AS Pvt
),
Status_Pivoting AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT
            CompanyID,
            'S' + [Year] AS [Year_Status],
            [Status]
        FROM @xyz
        ) AS sourcetable
        PIVOT (
        MIN([Status]) for [Year_Status] in ([S2015],[S2016],[S2017],[S2018]))
        AS Pvt
)
SELECT *
FROM Amount_Pivoting A
INNER JOIN Status_Pivoting S ON A.CompanyID = S.CompanyID;
```

Note - I have use `CTE` in this script to hold two pivots results. Please replace `@xyz` with your table name.